# Determine the volume of the solid that's bounded by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = 2z(x^2+y^2)$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Determine the volume of the solid that's bounded by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = 2z(x^2+y^2)$.

Transforming to spherical coordinates I have that $r^4 = 2r^3\cos(\varphi)\sin^2(\varphi)(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)) \Longrightarrow r = 2\cos(\varphi)\sin^2(\varphi)$ so $r \in [0, 2\cos(\varphi)\sin^2(\varphi)].$ How can I find the bounds for $\varphi$ and $\theta$? I feel a bit lost here...

Answer (score 1):

First a help in visualization:

[image: volume]

So surely $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$, as can be easily deduced from the equations once you realize $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and that $z \geq 0$.

Using the bounds on $r$ given above, the volume is then $\frac{2 \pi}{15}$.

Comment: Ooops... yep... thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From the original equation, we have that $z>0$ which means $\varphi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$. When the equation simplifies in spherical coordinates, there is no $\theta$ which means the shape is rotationally symmetric and thus $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$

Then looking at a graph of $r = 2\sin^2\varphi \cos\varphi$ on the restricted domain $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, the graph is $0$ at $\varphi = 0, \frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus the integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\varphi\int_0^{2\sin^2\varphi\cos\varphi}dr\:r^2\sin\varphi$$